# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Objects Exception

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I know that the class java.util.Objects is available from JDK 7 on. But the exception is just weird, it seems a call from within Java causes the exception -- but its the same VM isnt it?! Even "worse", Tomcat is configured to run with JRE7

```
05.Feb 00:01:00.485 <rker-5> ERROR [  org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool] - Error while executing the Runnable: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Objects
    at java.lang.StackTraceElement.equals(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxyUtil.findNumberOfCommonFrames(ThrowableProxyUtil.java:64) ~[logback-classic-0.9.28.jar:na]
```

Can you makse sense of this?

Comment: How have you verified that you are running with Java 7?

Comment: Err.. Tomcat Properties window tells me so... Java Virtual Machine: "C:\Programme\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll"

Comment: Are you running Terracotta?  It does funny thing to the internal classes which can produce these errors and it doesn't support Java 7

Comment: It could be a bug in the JVM. Which update do you have?

Comment: Which other vm's are installed on the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I have it... Java Updater has updated the day before to Update 13. The exception occured at the next cron job run. What do you think?

Comment: What was the actual solution?